# query on Xcode File owner and @property

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have got two basic questions about Xcode; I am from windows background and mostly code in C#.

First example project on a book got me to crate a single-view application, drop a label and button on view; drag to create outset and action; finally on .m file, write the code on button action click to change label.text. That's it: no setting File Owner or @property

Next example, also added a text-box and label.text gets updated with textBox value; over here I noticed that

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {}

doesn't raise if I don't drag textBox to FileOwner; that indicates for delegate handling, I need to connect to fileOwner. Is this assumption correct? 
In another example, tutorial actually shows me to connect a button to fileOwner - why would I need that?

Next question: on first example, I could change label.text without setting a @property; I could also read the textBox from second example. On another example, it uses @propery code - what I understood about @property that it's like a getter/setter in c#; in c#, I could get or set .text method for a textArea without any other settings; so why/when to use the @property.

I am sure that it's really simple, but I think I might be comparing it too much with c# and vb.

Update: I tried to look through three other books, but none of them actually explains why I am doing certain things (ie. linking to FileOwner). I am guessing a bit on FileOwner which is after playing with the code; but I don't understand why a button must be linked to fileOwner. If I drag it to create an event what else would I need to do with that?

For @property I read atomic/nonatomic, retail and I understand that; what I don't understand is, if I can read/write label, textArea, why would I need @property on that?

Rephrasing questions:

if I can get/set label.text = @"Hello"; why would I create a @propery and synthesise for that label?  or for a textArea with user input?

Next: why would the tutorial ask me to add a button to fileOwner?

Answer (score 0):

This programming paradigm is not exclusive to ios (as indicated by your tags), or even objective-C.  The delegate paradigm exists so that you can customize the behavior of a class without modifying the original class.  So for certain logic, the object will call out to its delegate to get instructions on how to proceed.

C# properties and objective-c properties are pretty much the same.  Both rely on underlying getter and setter methods to manipulate the value that is stored (private or protected) inside the class.  You could achieve the same thing through manual getter and setter methods (this is what most old hat C-programmers do when they start picking up objective-c, as far as I can tell), but you would lose something called KVO (key-value observation).  This is a system in objective-c which allows you to monitor via events when a property's value is changed.  You would also have a bunch of meaningless code...nobody needs 20 functions which all just set a member variable, so as in C# there is a shortcut for the compiler.  In C# this is the `{ get; set; }` pattern, and in Objective-C it is the `@synthesize` pattern.

So as for your example above, text is a **property** of the text field and textFieldShouldReturn is a **behavior**.  Custom behaviors are handled largely with delegate objects.  C# also has delegates, as I'm sure you know.  They are like function pointers, allowing you to set a function as a variable.  Objective-c delegate behavior is like setting a whole group of functions as a variable (some of which are optional, some of which are not) via a proxy object (usually a ViewController, but not by any means always).

I hope this clears things up for you, I am not great at putting things succinctly.  I also came from a C# background before Objective-C so that's why this question interested me.

Comment: Hey Borrden, thanks for quick reply; it's quite early in the morning and I had a long night.. I didn't really understand the answer, so could I please rephrase my questions:  if I can set label.text = @"Hello"; why would I create a @propery and synthesize  Next: why would the tutorial ask me to add a button to fileOwner? What custom behaviour does a button have? If I want to edit buttonText I understand that I need to create an Outset; but don't understand fileOwner part.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking.  You can set label.text **because** it is a property of UILabel.  You don't need to create another property just to do this.  I'm not sure what you are getting at with the whole fileOwner business.  File Owner is a phrase that usually comes from a XIB file.  Are you using XIB?